# modify a <DIV> element with CURL

Tags: php, javascript, html, curl

I know how to provide or modify a field with CURL curl_setopt function and to work with cookies, but what I could not find is how to modify an HTML element with CURL.

For instance, let's say I want to replace the function "submit_device_form" in below code

```
<div id="bottombuttons">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
  <!-- buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="separatorButton">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:submit_device_form(); return false;" class="buttonLink100">Set</a></td>
          <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:cancel_device_form(); return false;" class="buttonLink100">Cancel</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <!-- fixes the width of the first column -->
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="200" height="1" border="0" ></td>
      <td style="padding:0;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="360" height="1" border="0" ></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

with "submit_MY_form", a new JavaScript function included in my PHP script. How would I go for it?

I looked into the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" library since it provides the setAttribute and removeAttribute functions that would allow me to do that easily, but then I miss the info on how to give it access to the page read wia CURL, so I'm stuck.

Thanks for your help,

Robert

Comment: Why not just use str_replace?

Comment: It's the same issue I have with the PHP DOM functions: as far as I've learned so far, I have access to the HTML page "only" via the CURL functions.

Comment: As per your question i understand that, you need to remove the "submit_device_form()" from the code, use preg_replace


$result = preg_replace("/submit_device_form\(\)/","",$html);

Comment: @Nishu - Yes, that is the replacement operation I want to accomplish. I know that when I issue the curl_exec() function I get a "copy" of the HTML page. But that's only a "copy", am I right? So where is the "actual" page, because in my understanding that is what I must modify.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understand your question correctly.
But if you trying to modify the ORIGINAL page by curl. It's not possible.

Comment: @Hereblur - I'll answer with an example. After issuing  curl_exec() I get my page that is somewhere within the memory of my PHP process. I can modify "that" page using any CURL function that supports modifications, like, for instance the curl_setopt() function. CURL knows the page I want to modify because when I call  curl_setopt() I provide also the handle, which, as far as I know, it's a pointer to a more complex structure of pointers and variables one of which must be the pointer to the "actual" page. Hence I need to know the pointer from the CURL handle that point to the actual page.

Comment: When you call an remote location webpage using curl, its points to remote page and takes the copy of that page, this copy page is in store in memory for further process. Its a copy of the page. So you cant modify actual page using CURL (with my knowledge)

Comment: That's correct, I want to modify the page that is in local memory, not the one hosted by the server it has been downloaded from. Hence I need to know the pointer to "that" page in local memory. The HTML string returned by curl_exec() is the "copy of the copy" of the page.

Comment: Hmm, I think I start to understand my misunderstanding. The curl_exec() is only fetching the page from the site but not "displaying" it (it's a figurative expression) to a sort of internal (to PHP) browser, hence the code of the page doesn't get executed within the PHP contest as I thought it would. I will have to ask a different question.